# Удалить внешний ключ в sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как удалить сразу несколько внешних ключей в sql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Создайте новую таблицу аналогичной структуры.
- Перекиньте в неё данные.
- Удалите исходную таблицу.
- Переименуйте новую.

Comment: в бд у меня более 50 таблиц)

Comment: Тогда можно написать процедурный код, который в цикле удалит все ограничения, полученные из метаданных.

Или импортировать таблицы в другую базу. При этом теряются ограничения.

Comment: а как можно создать несколько первичных ключей по ID

Comment: Процедурно в цикле, используя динамический SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table [your_table]
drop constraint [constraint_name]
```

Как вариант.
Если вам не известны названия ваших констрейнтов, вы можете средствами `sql server management studio` создать скрипт на `create` вашей искомой таблицы, и в нем найти названия ключей.